# SQL to Linq for inner and left join together

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

My sql query is

```
SELECT T.TicketId,
         T.Subject,
         T.Issue,
         T.Priority,
         T.StatusId,
         T.Attachment,
         T.CreatedDate,
         T.ModifiedDate,
         T.Comment,
         U.Username as CreatedBy,
         TU.Username as Assigned
  FROM   tblTicket T
         INNER JOIN tblUser U
                    ON T.CreatedBy = U.UserId
         LEFT JOIN tblUser TU
                    ON T.AssignTo = TU.UserId
```

And I have tried to convert it in linq by below query

```
from ticket in tblTickets
join user in tblUsers
       on     ticket.CreatedBy equals user.UserId
into temp from tblUsers in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
       ticket.TicketId,
       ticket.Subject,
       ticket.Issue,
       ticket.Priority,
       ticket.StatusId,
       ticket.Attachment,
       ticket.CreatedDate,
       ticket.ModifiedDate,
       ticket.Comment,
       user.Username
}
```

And I am getting below error in linq pad

> The range variable 'tblUsers' conflicts with a previous declaration of
>   'tblUsers'

I know I am repeating the table for the left but variable name user and temp I mean not same so why I am getting this error and what is correct linq query for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are reusing the same variable name in your Linq2SQL query as the error suggests.

Take notice that in the Linq syntax `from item in table` and `join item2 in table2 ...` both the `item` & `item2` are a new variable declarations.

Something like this should fix it. See how I replaced the second use of the `tblUsers` with a new variable `userAssignedLeft`.

```
from ticket in tblTickets
join user in tblUsers on ticket.CreatedBy equals user.UserId
join userAssigned in tblUsers on ticket.AssignTo equals userAssigned.UserId into temp 
from userAssignedLeft in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
       ticket.TicketId,
       ticket.Subject,
       ticket.Issue,
       ticket.Priority,
       ticket.StatusId,
       ticket.Attachment,
       ticket.CreatedDate,
       ticket.ModifiedDate,
       ticket.Comment,
       UsernameCreatedBy = user.Username,
       UsernameAssigned = userAssignedLeft.Username
}
```

Comment: Where is T.AssignTo = TU.UserId ?

Comment: @PalaniKumar Thanks for the suggestion. Completely overlooked the second part of the question

Comment: @PalaniKumar For the null check in the left join part. Actually there is no need to check for nulls when projecting left joins in Linq2SQL, Linq2Entities only in Linq2Objects (in memory). Since this is a Linq2Sql query it does not improve readability. That is why I rejected the edit. Cheers

Comment: If it is not throws exception then fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
from ticket in tblTickets
join user in tblUsers
       on ticket.CreatedBy equals user.UserId
into temp from user  in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
     ticket.TicketId,
     ticket.Subject,
     ticket.Issue,
     ticket.Priority,
     ticket.StatusId,
     ticket.Attachment,
     ticket.CreatedDate,
     ticket.ModifiedDate,
     ticket.Comment,
     temp.Username
}
```

Answer (score 0):

variable 'tbluser' is already used in that query only, that why getting error.

```
from ticket in tblTickets
join user in tblUsers on ticket.CreatedBy equals user.UserId into temp 
from userLeft in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
   ticket.TicketId,
   ticket.Subject,
   ticket.Issue,
   ticket.Priority,
   ticket.StatusId,
   ticket.Attachment,
   ticket.CreatedDate,
   ticket.ModifiedDate,
   ticket.Comment,
  (userLeft == null ? String.Empty : userLeft.Username)
}
```

right table may contain null. so, it is good to check null for right table

Comment: Actually there is no need to check for nulls when projecting left joins in Linq2SQL Linq2Entities only in Linq2Objects (in memory).